# Headers to indicate that websocket server doesn't support any extensions

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

We've got a problem with Chrome 19 websockets. It is attempting to connect to our server using  the `x-webkit-deflate-frame` extension. However, I can't work out how to indicate to that client that we don't support that extension (or if it's a Chrome 19 bug and is just ignoring the fact that we don't support it?). I have seen this problem related in a few SO answers but I can't see a consistent solution.

For example, if we receive the headers

```
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: titantest:30100
Origin: http://titantest
Sec-WebSocket-Key: f+7h4rrKKqdRRdD7WwTZow==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
```

What should we respond with?

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 3eazAhsFLXFWB1OjcYMtzP13yag=
```

and then appended to that I've tried various `Sec-WebSocket-Extension` varieties

```
Sec-WebSocket-Extension: '-'
Sec-WebSocket-Extension: -
Sec-WebSocket-Extension: 
<- blank: don't send a Sec-WebSocket-Extension header ->
```

I've also got a copy of the websocket protocol in front of me, so feel free to point out what I've missed/misread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 9.1 of RFC 6455 deals with extension negotiation.

A client proposes a list of extensions and the server chooses from those proposed which it wants to accept and indicates that choice using its return Sec-WebSocket-Extensions header. It can accept none by not including the extension header at all in the server handshake response.

Is chrome 19 having a specific problem when you return no extension header?

Comment: Not sure how I missed that sentence! Chrome 19 is still sending through messages that are unmasked after we return our handshake response with no `Sec-Websocket-Extensions` header, whereas I'm under the impression that clients **must** mask their websocket frames (at least when no extensions have been negotiated). It appears to work fine in Chrome 20 and Chrome <=18.

Answer (score 0):

Omitting Sec-WebSocket-Extension from the response is the right way to go.

You will also need to make sure that you are unmasking the received data.  If you're just trying to receive text, it will appear garbled unless it is unmasked.

This site has a pretty explanation about how to unmask the data received over a websocket connection:
http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2012/9/24/websockets-101/